# How-to avoid warning when using conditional expressions in an aggregation (polars)

Tags: python-polars

Given I have a data frame

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group": [1, 1, 2, 2],
    "value": [10, Null, 30, Null],
})
```

I can fill the null values of the series using `fill_null` and aggregate in a single step:

```py
df.groupby("group").agg(
    pl.col("value").fill_null(20).min()
)
```

I could do the same using a conditional expression and then aggregating over this conditional expressions as well:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("value").is_null()).then(pl.lit(20)).otherwise(pl.col("value"))
).groupby("group").agg(
    pl.col("value").min()
)
```

However, creating the series on the fly during aggregation results in a warning:

```py
df.groupby("group").agg(
    pl.when(pl.col("value").is_null()).then(pl.lit(20)).otherwise(pl.col("value")).min()
)
# The predicate 'col("value").is_null()' in 'when->then->otherwise' is not a valid aggregation
# and might produce a different number of rows than the groupby operation would.
# This behavior is experimental and may be subject to change
```

The warning does not seem to be applicable in this case, as applying the conditional expression is equivalent to `fill_null` which does not result in a warning.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of the warning when using conditional expressions to transform series inside an aggregation?

Comment: It looks like you can get rid of the warning by reducing the result with `pl.all`/`pl.any`: `pl.when(pl.all(pl.col("value").is_null()))`

Comment: So cool, that seems to be the solution. I'm not sure what is going on here, since `pl.all`/`pl.any` does not seem to make a difference?!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why it removes the warning, I was just experimenting and noticed that it did. The expression doesn't really make sense to read.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `agg` [it checks if the expression you're trying to aggregate is valid](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/f7f675329b0a3fce6f0196377f28f867e59a8bb5/polars/polars-lazy/src/physical_plan/expressions/ternary.rs#L131). There are cases (I'm sorry I don't have a counter example) where an expression, as an aggregation, will yield unexpected results, in the form of the wrong number of rows. This warning is trying to bring this to your attention. Using `pl.all` or `pl.any` doesn't fix the issue. It merely sidesteps or hides what you're doing from that check. In this toy example you get the expected result but this warning is trying to tell you not to count on that. If you have more complex examples, you might discover that you get a result which doesn't make sense (in the best case because you can make corrective actions) or a wrong result without realizing it.